# Build executable for windows with Vue CLI Plugin Electron Builder in linux

Tags: electron, electron-builder, vue-cli-3, electron-packager

I'm trying to build an executable file for windows from my linux but so far I have not been able to do it.

According to the [documentation,](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/configuration.html#bundling-options) it tells me that here I could configure, for example, the output folder.

```
pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      outputDir: 'desktop-for-windows',
    },
  },
```

and if it works but does not say anything about how to change the platform (s.o) to build.
also try testing the following command:

```
npm run electron:build --win
```

but by default it builds for linux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ran into same thing trying to move from an older boiler plate to using Vue-CLI 3 just now.

Run this from within the project directory and see if it works:
`./node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service electron:build --windows`

I got the `--windows` from the `ui.js` file in the `vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder` directory under `node_modules`. Other options are `--linux` and `--macos`. I'm surprised I don't see a `--all` flag or that all isn't the default.

If you add `"build:win": "vue-cli-service electron:build --windows"` under `scripts` in your `package.json` then you can instead run `npm run build:win` from there on.

Comment: No prob. Glad to hear it. :)

Comment: How can I add certificate while create=ing build using electron-builder

Answer (score 2):

I just faced the same problem and found pretty easy answer.
You can just run `npm run electron:build -- --linux deb --win nsis` in the project directory.

There is more about it here: https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/recipes.html#multi-platform-build

Comment: How can I add certificate while create=ing build using electron-builder?